# Case auto-response email with empty subject

Tags: case

What I want to do is when I send an auto-response of a new case I want the subject of the case to be put in the subject of the email (dynamic subject). I Created a visualforce email template like the one below:

```
 <messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!RelatedTo.Subject}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Case">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Subject: {!RelatedTo.Subject}
Congratulations!
This is your new Visualforce Email Template.
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

But the email that arrives has an empty subject.

Does anyone know why this happens? If I put {!RelatedTo.Status} instead of the subject in the email appear the status on the subject of the email :/

Comment: and `Subject: {!RelatedTo.Subject}` in the body displays correctly?

Comment: Nope. It's empty :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.It was enough to put only {!case.subject} in the "Subject" field when creating a template that is not with a visualforce

[image]